# String Builder Appending value in middle of existing appendage

Tags: vb.net, stringbuilder

I have Dims I am referencing to Append a String, however my requirement requests that I split up one of my previous Dims I am appending. Please see the example below to show you what i am trying to get at. Basically  i need a way for my newest Dim added to go smack dab in the middle of an existing Dim that's already been appended.   **Note: Dim a can be dynamic so I don't know the number of characters it will return.

I am using the StringBuilder functionality in VB.

```
Dim sb = New StringBuilder()

Dim a = someValueForA

Dim b = someValueForB

Dim c = someValueForC

Dim d = someValueForD

sb.AppendFormat("-{0}",a)
sb.AppendFormat("-{0}",b)
sb.AppendFormat("-{0}",c)

result = "someValueAsomeValueBsomeValueC"
```

now i need to insert d right in the middle of "C" so as to look something like this:

```
result = "someValueAsomeValueBsomesomeValueDValueC"
```

Comment: I guess add the lengths of a and b and then try `sb.Insert` at that position.

Comment: I would think you would not need .AppendFormat since interpolated strings have been available in vb.net since Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I know you have tried to abstract your question to make it easier to get an answer but if you could share the real world application of this abstract maybe we could suggest an easier approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate the position and then use `sb.Insert`:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
   Dim sb = New StringBuilder()
   Dim a = "someValueA"
   Dim b = "someValueB"
   Dim c = "someValueC"
   Dim d = "someValueD"

   sb.AppendFormat("-{0}", a)
   sb.AppendFormat("-{0}", b)
   sb.AppendFormat("-{0}", c)
   sb.Insert(sb.Length - (c.Length \ 2), d)

   MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString())
End Sub
```